# Applying Multivariate Ito's Lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am having trouble applying Ito's Formula to the following:

Let $Z_t = W_{1t}^2  e^{W_{1t}+ \int_0^t W_{3s}dW_{2s}}$. Find $dZ_t$. $W_1,W_2,W_3$ are independent Brownian motions.

I know the formula but I am having trouble differentiating the integral with respect to $W_2$ and $W_3$.

Comment: Try using Ito's lemma in two variables where you consider the semimartingales $W_{1,t}$ and $\int_0^t W_{3,s} dW_{2,s}$.

Comment: @RhysSteele, I thought of that, but I am having trouble differentiating $\int W_{3,s} d W_{2,s}$ with respect to $W_{3,s}$. Can I just use the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: $d \int_0^{t}W_{3,s}dW_{2t}=W_{3,s}dW_{2t}$. The stochastic differential is just a type of short hand for a stochastic integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_t := \int_0^t W_{3,s} dW_{2,s}$.  As pointed out by @fesman in the comments, we have $dA_t = W_{3,t}dW_{2,t}$.  Note that this is just notation for how we defined $A_t$, we are not actually differentiating anything.  Then we have $Z_t = W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t} + A_t}$, and Ito's formula gives

\begin{align*}
dZ_t &= (W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + 2 W_{1,t} e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}) dW_{1,t} + W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} dA_t \\
& \qquad + (W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + 4 W_{1,t} e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}  +2e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}) dW_{1,t}dW_{1,t} + W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} dA_t dA_t \\
&= (W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + 2 W_{1,t} e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}) dW_{1,t} + W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} W_{3,t}dW_{2,t} \\
& \qquad+ (W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + 4 W_{1,t} e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}  +2e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}) dt + W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} W_{3,t}^2dt.
\end{align*}

Again, to emphasize, we have not differentiated $Z_t$.  This is just notation for $$Z_T = \int_0^T (W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + 2 W_{1,t} e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}) dW_{1,t} +\int_0^T W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} W_{3,t}dW_{2,t} + \int_0^T (W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + 4 W_{1,t} e^{W_{1,t}+A_t}  +2e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} + W_{1,t}^2 e^{W_{1,t}+A_t} W_{3,t}^2) dt.$$

Comment: This is an amazing answer. If you don't mind me asking, what is your academic background? I would guess a PhD in Probability or similar?

Comment: No problem!  I'm still working on my math PhD, with a research focus in financial mathematics and stochastic processes.

Comment: Consider joining https://quant.stackexchange.com/ , I see you're a good contributor and the Quant Finance community on quant.stackexchange always appreciates mathematically solid contributors such as yourself.